# 3 колонки поломались в safari

Tags: вёрстка, css

Помогите, пожалуйста, поправить вёрстку.

[Страница](http://prozaik.16mb.com/html5_2/q/) в большинстве браузеров отображается

[image: так]

Но в `win safari 5.1.7`

[image: так]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для *.auth_area* и *.logo_area* установить **float: left;**

Comment: о! помогло. спасибо